# Git - Can you find what client was used to push?

Tags: git

There are multiple ways to commit and push git commits.

- command line
- browser editor (github, gitlab)
- sourcetree (Update: sourcetree *does* support --signoff)
- tower
- github desktop

By looking at public history of a repo on github, is there any way to determine what percentage of git commits were made with the command line vs a git gui tool?

**Reasoning**

We are trying to determine how detrimental it would be to [mandate that users commit](https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/pull/213) with `git commit --signoff` (Instead of contributor license agreements). No git gui tools I've found support `--signoff`

Comment: Probably not; most Git frontends I've seen just invoke the command line tools under the hood. Unless they sign the commit message somehow, I suspect you won't be able to get this from the history.

Comment: i would enforce a server side git commit hook which checks whether the commit msg has a signoff.

Comment: FWIW Atlassian Sourcetree does support signoff.

Comment: Suggest to the authors of the relevant tools that this would be a useful feature. For open source tools, I'm sure a pull request would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't. Git commits do not capture or store this information.

A Git commit contains a tree ref, an author string, a committer string, a time stamp and a commit message. Nothing else.

You can inspect the contents of a commit (as in, these five pieces of data captured by a commit, not the tree it points to) using

```
$ git cat-file -p <commit_id>
```